# Using Web Audio API Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, promise, ionic2, web-audio-api

I am having problems with using the Web Audio API in ionic 2. No matter what I try I get errors. What I have gathered is that it is a problem with the typescript compiler. And tried adding the "es2015.promise", but did not work.
I get the error message:

```
  Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'.
  L10:      .then(function () { console.log("Accepted")})
  L11:      .catch(function () { console.log("Rejected"); });
```

my code looks like

```
this.audio = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(function () { console.log("Accepted")})
    .catch(function () { console.log("Rejected"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question, I ended up downloading the Visual Studio 2017 Release Candidate to get a newer version of intellisense. 
Found I could not use javascript's catch. So the code ended up looking like.

```
this.audio = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream)=>{console.log(stream);}, (err) => { console.log(err); })
```